# Solving a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica doesn't want to solve my exact system with 3 equations and 3 variables.

```
AdjustPar20[x_] := a x^b Exp[c x]
Solve[AdjustPar20[0.05] == 9.37126 && AdjustPar20'[0.05] == 0 && 
  AdjustPar20[0] == 0, {a, b, c}]
```

As an explanations why this cannot be solved the program replies:

```
{}
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; 
             use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Solve[]` works much better with exact arithmetic:

```
AdjustPar20[x_] := a x^b Exp[c x]
p = 937126/100000;
sol = Solve[
           AdjustPar20[5/100] == p && 
           ((D[AdjustPar20[t], t] == 0) /. t -> 5/100) &&
           AdjustPar20[0] == 0, {a, b, c}, Reals]

ParametricPlot3D[{a, b, c} /. sol, {a, p, 10 p},
                 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}, Automatic}, 
                 AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Please note that `AdjustPar20[0] == 0` isn't adding any information since your selected function form already ensures it

Comment: Note that `AdjustPar20[0] == 0` isn't adding information since your selected function form already ensures it.

Comment: How does one know to solve with these circumstances (rational numbers, real domain)?

Comment: @BoLe, in general, inexact numbers and `Solve[]` don't mix too well...

Comment: @
belisarius thanks for you suggestion, but my version of Mathematica, 8, cannot solve this. 

    Solve::ivar: 298.48501198004965` is not a valid variable. >>
    Solve[2.687648609756841*10^-437 a == 9.37126 && 
      1.007466030596621*10^-433 a == 0 && 
      3.211110349737091*10^-722 a == 0.01, {a, 298.485, -2221.2}, Reals]

Do you think I should define one more equation(instead of the 3rd one), in order to get one exact value of a?

Comment: @Gasper It works OK. in Mathematica 8. Start a fresh Mathematica session and retry it.

Comment: @belisarius Yes. But I still need to define one more equation, so "a" will have only one value and not a>(468563/50000). Thanks!

Comment: @Gasper Yes, you need one more equation. But we can't help with that since the equation should represent your problem conditions ... and we ignore them-